# Laravel setting images path

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to change paths for my images. The images are stored in `public\image`. I was using `src="image/name"` on my laravel project in locan and now  I want to put it on the internet.

But `src="asset('image/logo.jpg')"` doesn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use blade syntax correctly.
Try using:

```
src={{ asset('image/logo.png') }}
```

if that doesn't work, try:

```
src={{ url('/').'/image/logo.png' }}
```

Comment: Accept it as answer :)